# CodeGen_PECL and PEAR

Tags: pear

I can't install CodeGen through PEAR:

```
$ pear install CodeGen
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/CodeGen"
install failed
```

And, accordingly, I can't install CodeGen_PECL with the same error message.

```
$ pear install CodeGen-1.0.7
```

fails as well.

http://pear.php.net/CodeGen/ — I see it does exist, what's the problem?

Or maybe is there any another working tool for generating PECL extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, epic, I've added "sudo" and now it works. It looks like it couldn't write to cache dir, but error message is confusing.